# faster way to extract key value from string using pure JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I have string that contains key value separated by diff. kind of chars.
I need to use pure JavaScript ( no lib like jquery or ecma 5 or 6) regx or logic that is faster to extract key value and create javasciprt object.

string can be like as following and it will be not so long .mostly i can have 2 or 3 key value pairs.

"key!value~key!value"

"c!XXXXXXX~e!YYYYY~k!YYXXXX~d!"  where "~" separate between key value and "!" 
separates between key and value.
Out put after parsting string will be 
{c:"XXXXXXX",e:"YYYYY",k:"YYXXXX",d:''}

Is Regx is faster and what can be pattern?
or normal forloop and split function will be faster?

Comment: You can solve your own performance-based questions with https://jsperf.com/

Comment: I m looking for regx pattern for this if i can use

Comment: (\w+)!([^~]+)/ig - not sure if this is right one

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use regex to separate the key-value pairs just use split function of string object. use code :

```
const KV_SEP = "!";
const ENTITY_SEP = "~";
"c!XXXXXXX~e!YYYYY~k!YYXXXX~d!".split(ENTITY_SEP).map(function(val){
    return [val.split(KV_SEP)];
});
```

Comment: It will give u array of arrays. where internal array will contain key and value at its 0th and 1st index respectively.

Answer (score 0):

This is regex version

```
function splitString(str) {
  const KEY_INDEX = 1
  const VALUE_INDEX = 2


  const myKeyValue = {}
  const myRegex = /(?:([a-z])!([a-zA-z]*)~?)/g

  while(1) {
    match = myRegex.exec(str)
    if (match === null) break
    myKeyValue[match[KEY_INDEX]] = match[VALUE_INDEX]
  }

  return myKeyValue
}

console.log('result:', splitString('c!XXXXXXX~e!YYYYY~k!YYXXXX'))
```